# Greek typewriter characters with \symtt (or \mathtt)

Tags: unicode-math, greek, typewriter, math-fonts

I want to have Greek typewriter characters in math mode, using `unicode-math`.

I use a font having Greek characters:

```
\setmonofont{NewCMMono10}[
    Extension           = .otf,
    UprightFont         = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont          = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldFont            = *-Bold.otf,
    BoldItalicFont      = *-BoldOblique.otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures   = {Numbers=OldStyle}
]
```

but none of the following work: `\symtt{\Omega}`, `\symtt{Ω}` (these two produce the normal Omega), `\mathtt{\Omega}` (this one produces a boxed `?` as if the character was missing).

Adding this:

```
\setmathfont{NewCMMono10-Regular.otf}[
    range               = {tt},
]
```

doesn't help.

Comment: There is no Greek in the “MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE” group of characters in Unicode.

Comment: I know, but isn't there an easy way to insert the Greek letters from the text monospace font?

Comment: Not with `\symtt`.

Comment: Would these symbols have any semantic meaning, other than what we used to use in the age of typewriters? For example Φ we stll use it in AutoCad drawings meaning diameter, but I have not seen any typewriter math symbols used in Pure Maths. How would these be tagged in a pdf? Can you please comment as to were you want to use these?

Comment: I'm doing theoretical computer science and I manipulate both syntactic and semantic objects. I want the typography to distinguish between the two kind of objects, and typewriter font is a reasonable choice for syntax. Some of this syntactic objects are traditionally named with Greek letters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

`\symtt` is restricted to the unfortunately restricted set of characters specified by Unicode, but you can declare the font as a math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10}[
    NFSSFamily=ncmtt,
    Extension           = .otf,
    UprightFont         = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont          = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldFont            = *-Bold.otf,
    BoldItalicFont      = *-BoldOblique.otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures   = {Numbers=OldStyle}
]

\SetMathAlphabet\mathtt{normal}{TU}{ncmtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathttit{TU}{ncmtt}{m}{it}

\begin{document}
\showoutput

$\mathtt{abc αβγ}$
$\mathttit{abc αβγ}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You can define a math alphabet. Here I also present how to support the standard names in the input, so not to be forced to use Greek characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10}[
    NFSSFamily          = ncmtt,
    Extension           = .otf,
    UprightFont         = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont          = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldFont            = *-Bold.otf,
    BoldItalicFont      = *-BoldOblique.otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures   = {Numbers=OldStyle}
]

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathttinner}{TU}{ncmtt}{m}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xmathtt}{m}
 {
  \mathttinner { \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \sparusaurata_mathtt:n }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \sparusaurata_mathtt:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {\Alpha}{Α}    {\Beta}{Β}   {\Gamma}{Γ}    {\Delta}{Δ}
    {\Epsilon}{Ε}  {\Zeta}{Ζ}   {\Eta}{Η}      {\Theta}{Θ}
    {\Iota}{Ι}     {\Kappa}{Κ}  {\Lambda}{Λ}   {\Mu}{Μ}
    {\Nu}{Ν}       {\Xi}{Ξ}     {\Omicron}{Ο}  {\Pi}{Π}
    {\Rho}{Ρ}      {\Sigma}{Σ}  {\Tau}{Τ}      {\Upsilon}{Υ}
    {\Phi}{Φ}      {\Chi}{Χ}    {\Psi}{Ψ}      {\Omega}{Ω}
    {\alpha}{α}    {\beta}{β}   {\gamma}{γ}    {\delta}{δ}
    {\epsilon}{ε}  {\zeta}{ζ}   {\eta}{η}      {\theta}{θ}
    {\iota}{ι}     {\kappa}{κ}  {\lambda}{λ}   {\mu}{μ}
    {\nu}{ν}       {\xi}{ξ}     {\omicron}{ο}  {\pi}{π}
    {\rho}{ρ}      {\sigma}{σ}  {\tau}{τ}      {\upsilon}{υ}
    {\phi}{φ}      {\chi}{χ}    {\psi}{ψ}      {\omega}{ω}
    {\vartheta}{ϑ}
    {\varsigma}{ς}
    {\varphi}{ϕ}
    {\varpi}{ϖ}
   }
   {#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\xmathtt{abcαβγφϕΩ\alpha\beta\gamma\phi\varphi\Omega\varsigma}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on your preferences or the chosen font, you may want to swap the Greek characters for `\phi` and `\varphi`.

Comment: Would these symbols have any semantic meaning, other than what we used to use in the age of typewriters? For example Φ we stll use it in AutoCad drawings meaning diameter, but I have not seen any typewriter math symbols used in Pure Maths. How would these be tagged in a pdf?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides You should ask the OP.

Comment: Thanks. I just did.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{NewCMMono10}[
    Extension           = .otf,
    UprightFont         = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont          = *-Italic.otf,
    BoldFont            = *-Bold.otf,
    BoldItalicFont      = *-BoldOblique.otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures   = {Numbers=OldStyle}
]

% Define a custom command for Greek typewriter characters
\newcommand{\greektexttt}[1]{\ensuremath{\text{\texttt{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

In math mode: $\greektexttt{abcαβγφϕΩΞεϖρ}$

\end{document}
```